# error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>::iterator ...' to 'const char* for argument '1' ...'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char, std, gnu

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal
_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' 
to 'int remove(const char*)'
```

For some reason, my program compiles perfectly when I'm working on a Mac... but once I use a Linux machine, this error pops up in more than one place.

Here's one of the instances where the error pops up:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(string t, string art, Time dur) {
    char chars[] = ",";
    t.erase(std::remove(t.begin(), t.end(), chars[0]), t.end());
    art.erase(std::remove(art.begin(), art.end(), chars[0]), art.end());
    // Some more code ...
}
```

More specifically, the error is coming from this line:

```
t.erase(std::remove(t.begin(), t.end(), chars[0]), t.end());
```

Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Comment: It is working [here](https://ideone.com/jZh5x5).  Can you produce an [mcve]?

Comment: Its not picking up the right remove function, did you include <algorithm> ? (Sadly theres another remove in <cstdio>)

Comment: Read the compiler error properly. You missed out the important part in the question title. It tells you it is trying to call `int remove(const char*)` which is clearly not the function you want to call.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <algorithm>`, where [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) is located. Without that, your compiler only knows about [this `std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) (I get the same error with Visual C++ 14), which is defined in indirectly included `<cstdio>` header.

Different behavior among compilers is a result of different `#include` hierarchies of the standard library implementations.